# Reuse structured binding variables when using a local struct

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function as follows:

```cpp
auto foo(int i) {
    struct s {
        int i;
        std::string name;
    };

    return s{i+10, "hello there"};
}
```

And it works fine with structured bindings:

```cpp
auto [i, name] = foo(10);
```

Is there a way to reuse the variables? i.e.

```cpp
// Later in the code.
[i, name] = foo(20);
```

It doesn't work with `std::tie` because I'm not returning a tuple. I prefer a struct as it feels cleaner to me than a tuple. But if there is no other alternative, I'm open to switching to a tuple.

Comment: What is the goal here? Why rip them out of the structure in the first place? Is it really that much fuss to `x.i` instead?

Comment: Structured binding is only possible during variable definitions. It's not possible to use in plain assignments.

Comment: @tadman - My actual function takes a `vector` of objects and returns boolean flags if certain criteria are met for the objects within the vector. I have no need of the struct in the calling function since the purpose of each flag is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the hidden variable introduced by a structured binding is unnamed, there's no easy way to refer to it to a assign a new value.

You could do

```
auto x = foo(10);
const auto &[i, name] = x;
```

Then assign to `x` to change the meaning of `i` and `name`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It feels a bit like magic but I think it works well for my use case. :)

Comment: @PlastyGrove it might be cleaner to just use a tuple in this case.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - Perhaps you're right. I'll then be able to use `std::tie`.

Comment: Clever.  Maybe a bit _too_ clever...